# How to set quality option on all images without using querystring?

Tags: imageresizer

Using https://imageresizing.net, how to set default quality so that **all** jpg and pngs are rendered with quality=90 without using querystring?

All photos should rendered like this:
https://azure.content.bloc.net/widget/200000184/363/2017/10/5/adam---eva-11.09.177001-copy.png?quality=90

without having to specify querystrings:
https://azure.content.bloc.net/widget/200000184/363/2017/10/5/adam---eva-11.09.177001-copy.png

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a DefaultSettings plugin for imageresizing, but as far as I know it only works for scaling. 
Take a look at it here:

https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/defaultsettings

Comment: no quality options in the DefaultSettings plugin (according to the documentation at least)

Comment: @Joakim they might be able to help you or at least the next person if you write to them, or at least on the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in my custom plugin. I've created a custom virtual image provider, and I implemented the interface ISettingsModifier. Using it i managed to set the quality I wanted without using querystring.

```
public ResizeSettings Modify(ResizeSettings settings)
    {
        settings.Quality = 50;
        return settings;
    }
```